# Visible seams in wall paneling, seams not centered

Tags: woodworking, contractors, paneling

First time posting here so apologies in advance for newcomers mistakes.

TLDR; contractor installed shiplap and it has visible seams causing uneven board lengths, and the framing is completely off-center due to the installation method. Unsure if I should push to have it re-done and centered.

I hired a professional to install shiplap vertically for me in my older home. I had incorrectly assumed that, like a tiler, they would center their work and have cohesive seams throughout. They did part 1 today and in the middle of the wall, its like he cut two pieces of the shiplap in half vertically and lined them up together starting on opposite ends of the wall, working inwards. This resulted in the boards joining unevenly in the center of the wall.

Additionally, for the ceiling, he started on one edge, and continued through to the edge on the other room. He used beams of wood to cover the seams/frame the room. The problem here is that because he started on edge, and used beams to cover the seams, the entire ceiling loses its symmetry be because the beams aren't centered. Instead, they match his seams starting from the edge.

He has to come back tomorrow... is this something I can ask him to fix? It seems like a big deal to fix it, but it seems completely wrong when it comes to installation and he wasn't exactly cheap to hire either so between having materials wasted and having the quality be poor and I'm not sure what to do.

FWIW, he said he was taking a drywall approach of having less cuts and that's why he made it off-center.

As noted, the job is only half complete, so these pictures show that half complete state.

[image: Uneven seam]

[image: Off center (you can tell by the centered light and where the boards stop]

Comment: Pictures would help.

Comment: Sounds like you two didn't communicate clearly to set expectations before the job.

Comment: I'm very confused. Shiplap siding shouldn't have visible "seams". There should be a line where each piece overlaps the next, but not seams... Pictures would be invaluable to help us see what you're seeing. Maybe an overview shot of the wall in question, then a couple of close ups.

Comment: The pictures show work done by a person not familiar with the materials or how to install them...unprofessional without a doubt.

Comment: For the wall, that’s a quirky detail, and you’re within your rights to ask for it to be reworked. The side pieces should be approximately the same width and all other boards should be full width. Regarding the ceiling, it’s not clear what’s wrong: maybe more pictures?